# Avoid showing non-existing image frames in html email template

Tags: html, email, html-email

I'm curious if there's way to avoid displaying error frames in email templates when image loading error occurs (for example image doesn't exist)? You can see it on the picture below. I have there kinda dynamic content.

I tried to set image `onerror="this.onerror=null;this.style='display:none;'"` but I wasn't surprised it doesn't work :D

[image]

Comment: you can serve a default error image in such case

Comment: @Raphael but is it possible to do via html in email template or not?

Comment: yes, emails are being shown in webView so all the parsers are ready to be used

Answer (score 0):

This code will serve an image in case your correct is not being shown:

```
<img src="img/non_existing_image.jpg"
     onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals';"
/>
```

Alternatively you can serve a transparent 1x1 png file.

Comment: this also doesn't work in gmail client ... seems like `onerror` doesn't work at all

Comment: Have you set Content Secutiry Policy? it's required for files to being served correctly...

Answer (score 0):

You were close to the right answer - if you do not want to see any alternative image, this will work:

```
 <img src="incorrect_path_to_image"  onerror="this.onerror=null;this.style.display='none';"/>
```

Comment: well this doesn't work, I still see the frame when image is not found in gmail client